# DirectoryMatch not working under WAMP?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, wamp

I'd like to deny access to all directories which name is **"d"** or **"src"**.

What I tried is to use the `<DirectoryMatch>` directive into my .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /main.php?_rewrite_=1&_escaped_fragment_=/err/403
ErrorDocument 404 /main.php?_rewrite_=1&_escaped_fragment_=/err/404

#banned access
<DirectoryMatch "(d|src)">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</DirectoryMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(old\.php|directory\.php|rewrite\.php|htaccess|htpasswd|ini|log)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

DirectoryIndex main.php
Options -Indexes
```

But adding the `<DirectoryMatch>` rule, Apache is giving me a 500 Internal Error, and the same happens for the `<Directory>` rule.

I'm using a **Apache/2.4.9 (Win64)** **PHP/5.5.12** WAMP Server.

Comment: Of course it does. You are doing i wrong. `<DirectoryMatch>` requires a RegularExpression and yours is not. [See The Manual- as a last resort of course](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directorymatch)

Comment: You might also get better results if you use the Apache 2.4 permission syntax [See the Manual - again as a last resort](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require)

Comment: `(d|src)` is a regular expression, and the same like `"\.(old\.php|directory\.php|rewrite\.php|htaccess|htpasswd|ini|log)$"` works perfectly inside the Filesmatch block.

Comment: The documentation's example don't work for me, this is why I need help